# Erro em sistema de busca em php

Tags: php, pdo

Estou fazendo um sistema de busca, só que esta dando um erro, gostaria de saber a solução.

Segue o código:

```
<?php

require_once 'conect.php'; 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                $nome  = $_POST['nome'];
                $pdo = conexao::getInstance();
                $parametro = Array(':nome'=>'%'.$nome.'%');
                $sql  = ' SELECT * FROM doacao WHERE nome LIKE :nome ';

                try {
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindValue(1, $nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->execute($parametro);
                        $resultado = $stmt->FETCH(PDOStatement::fetch());
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }              



              echo '<strong>id:</strong> '       , $resultado->iddoacao       , '<br />';
              echo '<strong>nome:</strong> '     , $resultado->nome      , '<br />';
              echo '<strong>email:</strong> '    , $resultado->descricao    , '<br />';
              echo '<strong>criado em:</strong> ', $resultado->dataentrada , '<br />';
        }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <title>Read</title>
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Read</h1>
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                        <div><label for="nome">Nome</label><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /></div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

o erro que ta aparecendo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method PDOStatement::fetch()
>   cannot be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudread\index.php:15
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudread\index.php on
>   line 15.

Comment: No lugar de <code>PDOStatement::fetch()</code> tente usar <code>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC</code>

Comment: Mas tentei com dois nao deu certo, talvez vou ter que mudar a estrutura do array e arrumar pra funcionar.

Comment: Percebi que você está executando o comando ` $stmt->execute($parametro);` ao invés de executar com ` $stmt->execute($sql);`. Seria isso?